# renaming index names while exporting them as ddl

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, database-administration

in current existing schema most of the index/constraint names are generated by oracle like SYS_CXXXXX , am trying to export those as DDL statements, here i need to  replace system generated names with like PK_(tablename) or PK_(tablename)1. thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched anything about how to accomplish this?

Comment: did try this 
spool create_indexes.sql 
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX',u.index_name) DDL FROM USER_INDEXES u;
spool off;

with this am getting the existing index name in the create script, instead i am trying to replace with name  a which can be easily identified

Answer (score 1):

You can use RENAME option of ALTER command to rename constraints/indexes:

```
SQL> create table t (x int primary key);

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints
  2  where table_name = 'T';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                                                                 
----------------------
SYS_C0010667                                                                    

SQL> alter table t rename constraint sys_c0010667 to t_pk;


SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints
  2  where table_name = 'T';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                                                                 
----------------------
T_PK                                                                            

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes where table_name = 'T';

INDEX_NAME                                                                      
----------------------
SYS_C0010667                                                                    

SQL> alter index sys_c0010667 rename to t_pk;

Индекс изменен.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes where table_name = 'T';

INDEX_NAME                                                                      
----------------------
T_PK
```

Comment: thanks dmitry, this may workout if we need changes in existing schmema. but here i am trying to create schmea export script. this schema export results  some DDL statements, i am trying to rename index name in  DDL statemetns, which can allow us to have our identified index/constraint name

Comment: In this case you can mere replace object name in CLOB data GET_DDL function returns - using replace() function for example.